# Excel Locked Cells

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-excel

So I have a worksheet that I have exported and easily formatted without code from SharePoint. I have cells A11 through R11 that I want locked so when I refresh the column widths don't go back to normal as I wrapped the text. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I know VBA might have to be used and if so I would love a little description of why.

Comment: So are you asking how to lock cells? And what do you mean by 'refresh the column widths'?

Comment: I am exporting a list from SharePoint to Excel. I have cells that I want to change the column width but when I refresh with the new data coming in the widths change on certain cells...I know how to lock a worksheet but that locks the whole sheet, which I do not want.

Comment: Select all the cells >> Right click >> Format Cells >> Protection >> Uncheck Locked. Choose the columns you want to lock and repeat the process. Then protect by deselecting `Select Locked Cells`.

Comment: Does not work - As the cells go right back to the same width once I unlock, change, then repeat to lock the cells.

Comment: What do you mean `change, then repeat to lock`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will keep certain column widths from being adjusted:

```
1. Select all the cells
2. Right click and choose Format Cells
3. Go to Protection tab and uncheck Locked
4. Select the columns you want to lock and repeat steps 1-3 above (this time check Locked)
5. Go to Review tab and deselect Select Locked Cells.
6. Click okay
```

That should work for you.

Comment: You would think this wouldn't be this hard to lock the cell width but the above help still does not fix the width after refreshing.

Comment: You need to check Locked the second time through. See my edit.

Comment: @J.McCormick By the way, all of the above needs to be done BEFORE you do any refreshes. You must unlock everything, relock only the columns you want, and protect the columns you just relocked under `Review` tab >> `Protect Sheet` (deselecting `Select Locked Cells` before clicking okay to protect). THEN do your refresh. Hope it works! :-)

Comment: I actually just added a dialog box and that made my filtering option save. I tried all other options and it would not work but I really appreciate the help from everyone!